# C++ and Objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c

i built a static library,and add the `.h` file to my project,

in all the class in the `.h` files,something like this :

```
class StartOp
{
    static void openFiles(WavInFile **inFile, WavOutFile **outFile, const RunParameters *params);
    static void setup(SoundTouch *pSoundTouch, const WavInFile *inFile, const RunParameters *params);
    static void process(SoundTouch *pSoundTouch, WavInFile *inFile, WavOutFile *outFile);
    static void detectBPM(WavInFile *inFile, RunParameters *params);
    int start(const int nParams, const char * const paramStr[]);
};
```

i got this error:

```
StartOp.h:18: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'StartOp'
```

**EDIT****

i fix this problem by changing the file ex to mm.
now i want to use this code and i want to call from this class ,this code is an c++ class that i want to call him from an objective-c class:

```
#ifndef _STARTOP_H_
#define _STARTOP_H_

namespace soundtouch
{

    class StartOp
    {
        static void openFiles(WavInFile **inFile, WavOutFile **outFile, const RunParameters *params);
        static void setup(SoundTouch *pSoundTouch, const WavInFile *inFile, const RunParameters *params);
        static void process(SoundTouch *pSoundTouch, WavInFile *inFile, WavOutFile *outFile);
        static void detectBPM(WavInFile *inFile, RunParameters *params);
        static int start(const int nParams, const char * const paramStr[]);
    };
}



#endif
```

to the 
`static int start(const int nParams, const char * const paramStr[]);`

method from my objective-c iphone app.

Comment: `class` is neither C nor Objective-C. Looks more like C++

Comment: This is neither C nor Objective-C...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is not C; it is rather C++.

Now, Objective-C and C++ can interoperate, but you need to use `.mm` extensions on the Objective-C side.

So if you are importing the `.h.` file into a `.m` file, you get obviously errors because the compiler is not expecting a `class` definition (C++). If you import the `.h` file into a `.mm` file, you have some chance that it will work (if all the rest is correct, I mean).

If you need more help, please provide more code, so that we can understand better what you are doing.

Comment: about your second question: you should provide more detail about the `start` function... is it a C function, an ObjC method? more code would help...

Comment: i have a c++ code that i post and a function in this class and i want to know how i can call the start method that is in the c++ header from the objective-c file

Comment: If `static start...` is not inside any C++ class, remove the `static` keyword, and then simply call `start(...` from C++. static (in the global scope) makes the function visible only from within the file where it is defined.

Comment: but when i write this call : int tmp = StartOp.start();
in the objective-c code he give me an error : ExampleAppDelegate.mm:31:0 'StartOp' was not declared in this scope

and i make include to this StartOp class

Comment: You should use `StartOp::start()`, this is the correct syntax for calling a static class function...